# Bigquery multiple WITH clauses throwing error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery to run a query with multiple WITH clauses, as follows:

```
WITH subq_L1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        metric,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('{execution_date:s}'), TIMESTAMP(ds)) < 1, ds, NULL)) AS L1
    FROM
        [xxx:yyy.zzz]
    GROUP EACH BY
        id, metric
),
subq_L7 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        metric,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('{execution_date:s}'), TIMESTAMP(ds)) < 7, ds, NULL)) AS L7
    FROM
        [xxx:yyy.zzz]
    GROUP EACH BY
        id, metric
),
subq_L14 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        metric,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('{execution_date:s}'), TIMESTAMP(ds)) < 14, ds, NULL)) AS L14
    FROM
        [xxx:yyy.zzz]
    GROUP EACH BY
        id, metric
)
SELECT * FROM subq_L1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM subq_L7
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM subq_L14
```

The '{execution_date:s}' gets formatted by python into a date-string.

BigQuery keeps throwing this error:

```
Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>.
```

All the queries run successfully if they stand alone; it is only putting them inside the WITH clause that makes it unsuccessful.

Why are these not succeeding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WITH` works only with Standard SQL - see how to [Enable Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

Also, in standard SQL you should use `xxx.yyy.zzz` instead of [xxx:yyy.zzz]

**Note**:
It is also possible to enforce Standard SQL without code change.
Just make sure that the first line of your query is

```
#StandardSQL
```

and BigQuery will treat the rest of the query as Standard SQL

Comment: Also: 1). There is no GROUP EACH BY, just GROUP BY 2). DATE_DIFF works on DATE, TIMESTAMP_DIFF on TIMESTAMP